# Load C# date time to KendoUI Date picker

Tags: c#, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm Trying to Load DateTime to KendoUI DatetimePicker. But It shows like /Date(1381964400000)/. I need to get it Like 10/17/2013

this is my Code

date time picker:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("invDate")
```

Script for loading date time to control

```
$("#invLoad").click(function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Content("Invoice/ItemHeaderByTrnKy")",
                data: { trnNo: $('#trnNo').val() },
                dataType: "Json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {

                        $("#invDate").val(data.TrnDt);

                    }
                    else {
                        ClearAll();
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    ClearAll();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

The first option is to attempt to parse the string into a JavaScript `Date` object, then pass that object to the `kendoDatePicker` widget:

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data) {
        var dateval = parseInt(data.TrnDt.src.replace(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//, "$1"));
        if (!isNaN(dateval)) {
            var d = new Date(dateval);
            $("#invDate").data("kendoDatePicker").value(d);
    } else {
        ClearAll();
    }
},
```

Steps:

1. Extract the numeric value from the string with `data.TrnDt.src.replace(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//, "$1")` and parse to integer.
2. Create a `Date` object
3. Pass the `Date` object to the `kendoDatePicker`'s `value()` function.

While this mostly works, the result may not be precisely what you expect.  The .NET JSON encoding will likely produce a local time offset, while the `Date()` constructor expects a value as a UTC offset, then coverts to local time.  As a result your output will be offset by a number of hours depending on the timezone of the server and the timezone of the client.

On my client, parsing the date value you provided gives a result of `Thu Oct 17 2013 09:00:00 GMT+1000`.  This tells me that you are probably running in one of the GMT+0100 time-zones.

The only reliable way to get around this is the second option: return all of your Date values as strings that can be interpreted by the `Date()` constructor.

If you format the date value as `dd MMM yyyy` on the server and pass the resulting string to `new Date()` then you will get the date value you expected.  If you are simply returning an object via `return Json(result);` in the ASP controller, the simplest way to achieve this is to add a translation property to your object:

```
public string strTrnDt { get { return TrnDt.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"); } }
```

Then your code becomes:

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data) {
        var d = new Date(data.strTrnDt);
        $("#invDate").data("kendoDatePicker").value(d);
    } else {
        ClearAll();
    }
},
```

Or even simpler:

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data) {
        $("#invDate").val(data.strTrnDt);
    } else {
        ClearAll();
    }
},
```

Comment: Kendo UI has kendo.parseDate which supports this format out of the box.

Comment: @AtanasKorchev I plead ignorance, since I started using Kendo about a week ago :P

Comment: @AtanasKorchev The `kendo.parseDate()` method still suffers from timezone issues, but it greatly simplifies the conversion.